# How to do selective Mongo recovery?

Tags: mongodb, recovery

Suppose I have a `Mongo` replica set (a primary and few secondaries) with two databases: `db1` and `db2`. One secondary `Mongo` crashed and lost its data. Now when this `Mongo` restarts it will *recover* and copy *both* `db1` and `db2` from the primary.

Since such recovery takes a lot of time I would like this secondary Mongo to copy *only* `db1` (but *not* both `db1` and `db2`) upon recovery. Can I do it with Mongo 2.4.6 ?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB does not yet have the capacity for selective replication.

Feel free to open a JIRA: https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa there is probably already one but a Google search by me can't bring it up.

Of course, one option here, to sped things up, is to actually physically copy the data from one location to the other without waiting for MongoDBs replication to take hold.

As @Stennie mentions, this is actually the JIRA for selective replication: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1559

Comment: Thanks ("selective" is a better term, I will change the title). The physical copy you mentioned can be an interesting option. How would you do it ? Can I just "export" `db1` and "import"  it in the Mongo instead of recovering ?

Comment: @Michael exporting is one way but another way is to copy the data files directly, your database will be file named and you will actually be able to see it in your data folder, fortunately mongodbs data files are portable

Comment: @Michael: For a feature request you can watch/upvote [SERVER-1559](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1559) in the MongoDB issue tracker, which suggests adding a replica set node type that could store a subset of databases or collections. It is worth noting that this node would be different from the current notion of a *secondary* which provides for data redundancy and failover. A partial replica node could never become primary, and would be confusing for the semantics of [write concern](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/) if that node is allowed to acknowledge the write.

Comment: @Stennie Added to answer for reference :)