# Simulating selective recovery in Mongo. Will it work?

Tags: mongodb, database-replication

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703885/how-to-do-selective-mongo-recovery):

Suppose I want to *replicate* only part of the databases in Mongo. I know that Mongo does not provide selective replication. I am thinking over the following workaround:

- Export (I do not know how to do it in mongo) *only* the databases I want to replicate in primary;
- Remove the secondary instance I want to recover from the replica set;
- Import data to the secondary instance;
- Add the secondary instance to the replica set.

Will it work ?

I am afraid that the secondary instance will copy the rest of the databases once I added it to the replica set. Is it correct ?

Answer (score 1):

This will not work, also not a good idea. A replica set uses an oplog to propagate changes made to any database running on a given mongod instance.

Have you considered running a separate mongod instance containing the collection you wish to replicate?

Comment: @Michael With this option I believe you'll have to do the synchronisation yourself. And how will you know which entries are new/updated? If you end creating a script to dump and import all data the overhead may not be kind.